# Cannot pull post data from request.body

Tags: angularjs, node.js, post, express

This is my angular post request:

```
    var webCall = $http({
               method: 'POST',
               url: '/validation',
               async : true,
               headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'text/html'
               },
               data: {email: "abc@gmail.com"}});
   webCall.then(successHandler, errorHandler);
```

now in my nodejs server, following code extracts the post data:

```
app.post('/validation',function(req,res){
        req.on('data',function(data){
            console.log(data.toString());
        });
```

But consoling request body as:

```
app.post('/validation',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

consoles empty object.

Comment: Did you checked, what your javascript console says? I personally use $resource in place of $http and router.post/get/put/delete instead of app.post... Anyways paste your JS console error log, let's see what it says. Cheers.

Comment: it does not console error. it just consoles empty object as i told in the question.

Comment: Would you like to try with $resource? Then i can guide you with a very easy solution.

Comment: is it possible to make an ajax call using resource? If so then sure. I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Your problem is because you put the headers content-type to be `text/html`. Try to remove the `headers` in your `$http` or change it into `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: @themyth92 thanks a lot. It had been bugging me for so long. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

A possible reason could be that you haven't added (or shown in the question) the `body-parser` middleware.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// for parsing multipart/form-data
app.use(multer());
```

Add the relevant middleware **before** the `routes` for the data you're expecting to receive. In your case, it looks like you only need the first one. Also, as pointed out by @themyth92, pass the correct headers.

Read more [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html)

Comment: turns out I used wrong content-type "text/html" instead of "application/json"